# #Eval Short Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I am trying to add date From and date To to my products these values are store in my database as date. These are stored in this format `2013-01-15`. The format is not a problem but when I display them on my application the time appears (`1/15/2013 12:00:00 AM`) how can I remove the time please. Below you can find the method Im databound the data.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<% # Eval("soDateTo") %>' Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try String Formatting within the Eval statement:
[See ASP Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1231290.aspx/1)

There are several ways to format the date.

```
<asp:label id="DateAddedLabel" runat="server" text='<%#
Eval("DateAdded", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:label>
```

Comment: If the date happens to be null will this cause an exception? If so what is the best way to evaluate for null?

Comment: In that case you can make an "if-then-else" test, and provide some other return for values that are null. See this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012226/nullreferenceexception-handling-in-in-line-asp-net-code) post here for some guidance.

Answer (score 18):

Try this;

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<% # Eval("soDateTo", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to Daniel's solution, but it handles null:

```
<asp:label id="DateAddedLabel" runat="server" text=
    '<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DateAdded").ToString())) 
    ? "No Date Available" : Eval("DateAdded", "{0:d}") %>'>
</asp:label>
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered just fine, but I used to use a lot more `Label`s than were necessary and thought I'd offer a way without.

You can ignore the `Label` all together and put the *Eval(...)* method by itself.

For example if you are using this inside of a `TemplateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date To">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("soDateTo", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can use this to improve your CSS control a tad, such as

```
<div id="client_since">
    <%# Eval("soDateTo", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ToShortDateString` Method to get rid of the time part of the date:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<% # Eval("soDateTo", "{0:d}") %>'
> Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text='<%# (Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("soDateTo"))).ToShortDateString()  %>'></asp:Label>
```